# Application stops when using Vector<Mat> or List<Mat> in OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, list, opencv, vector, split

I am using OpenCV library for an Android project. The thing is that when I want to separate an image into its 3 channels (I only want to work with the green channel), I declare a `List<Mat>` in order to use `split()` method:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    input = inputFrame.rgba();      
    Vector<Mat> channels = new Vector<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(input, channels);        
    canny = channels.get(1);

    /*

    other code

    */

    return canny;
}
```

The problem is that in a 20-30 seconds (depending on camera resolution) my phone runs out of memory and closes the app. How can I clean the memory every time `onCameraFrame` is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem with the Java version so it seems to be a bug in the cv::split() wrapper. I now use the Core.extractChannel() for the same purpose and doesn't have memory leak.

```
Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
Mat yuv = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, yuv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb);
Mat y = new Mat();
Core.extractChannel(yuv, y, 0);
Mat u = new Mat();
Core.extractChannel(yuv, u, 1);
Mat v = new Mat();
Core.extractChannel(yuv, v, 2);
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the variable Mat into function "onCameraViewStarted"

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

    mRgba = new Mat();
    r = new Mat();
    g = new Mat();
    b = new Mat();


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please restrict your answers to responses that actually provide an answer to the problem stated in the question. Comments or requests for additional information should be restricted to comments, not answers. Answer one or two questions properly and you should have enough reputation to comment without restriction.